# Date Time in Code Igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I want to get my current system time in computer.

My system time is `7:59PM` so I tried to get it by this code

```
  echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

but it gives `2016-12-27 12:59:20`

How can I fix this?

I tried solution that adds application/config.php

```
application/config.php
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the server is located in a different state or have a different time zone, you should set the time zone same as your location

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
```

[**documentation**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
echo date('h:i A');
```